# Use of relays for sensor outputs.

Tags: variable

I am required to connect four different outputs from 4 sensors to a Digital input on a VACON 20 VSD (Variable speed drive). The application requires the VSD to stop the motors on detection of an obstruction on anyone of the sensors (Proximity sensors). I cannot use for digital inputs on the VSD and thus require the outputs to go through relays which will be connected in series. So, even if one of the sensor detects an obstruction the VSD stops. But I am not sure as to how the wiring of the relays can be done in series.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't give any details about voltages / NO or NC / Failsafe input or anything, so are you thinking something like the following circuit...

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fp1RlX.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The relays are in parallel, this way if any sensor detects an object the drive will get the stop signal. In series would require all of the sensors to be made to stop the drive (probably not what you want).